# If there are 2 matrices a and b, what does a(b) do in matlab?

Tags: linux, matlab, matrix

If I have a matrix, say

```
a = [1 2 3;
     4 5 6]
```

and

```
b = [2 2 2;
     3 3 3]
```

when I do a(b) in matlab, I get the answer as

```
a(b) = [4 4 4;
        2 2 2]
```

what exactly is happening here ?

Answer (score 4):

You're indexing a with each item in `b`. `a(2) = 4` and `a(3) = 2`

so

```
c = [a(2) a(2) a(2); a(3) a(3) a(3)]
```

is what you're seeing.